# How Do I Render Sidebar Content Dynamically Using Iron-Router?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, spacebars

I use Meteor with Spacebars. With Iron Router I use `main` template as layout template. I have this route:

/ -> app

```
{{#if currentUser}}
    {{> dashboard}}
{{else}}
    {{> home}}
{{/if}}
```

In the `main` template I have a navbar and a sidebar with menus. What I would love to be able to do is to change it's content depending on the template currently rendered. Something similiar to this:

```
{{if currentTemplate(dashboard)}}

{{else}}

{{/if}}
```

You get the picture. I guess that could be done with Meteor's helpers but I'm not 100% sure about that. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to set a session variable and change content based on its value.

What I do a lot is change navbar contents depending on the current route. I use the iron router active package to do this.

Comment: https://atmospherejs.com/zimme/active-route <- you mean this package? Seems like this is exactly what I need.

Comment: Yes. That's the package I was talking about